# Installing Vertica JDBC jar file in WIndows 7

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, vertica

Having trouble installing vertica_5.1.1_jdk_5 on my Windows 7 PC. I installed the latest Java SDK. When I type java -jar vertica_5.1.1_jdk_5.jar, I get "no main manifest attributes". I opened the MANIFEST file within the JAR, and found "Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.5.0_07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)". So from what I've read, I'm missing a Main Class statement in here. How do I figure out what to add to this MANIFEST file?

Comment: A JDBC driver does not need to be installed. You just tell your Java application to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A JDBC driver is a library to be used by a Java application. It is not a program itself, so it doesn't have a `Main-Class` attribute, and therefor cannot be run like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Senza - vertica does not ship the java libraries as a self installing application.  Instead they ship just the jar that you can include in your classpath for your application.  Are you trying to make it work with a specific application? If so, message me and I will send instructions on how to make it work.